# Downcasting pointer to member function. Is this legal usage?

Tags: c++, inheritance, language-lawyer, pointer-to-member

I store a list of pointers-to-member-function in an array.  I want to index into the array and execute the appropriate function.  There will be many arrays listing functions from different classes (all derived from Base), so the class is not known at compile time.

I have the scheme working, but I am not entirely happy with having to use a void pointer at one place, but I can't seem to avoid it.

Is my casting between Base and Derived member function pointers legal according to the C++11 standard(it is working with g++). I would appreciate language lawyer advice !

Below is a stripped down, but runnable version of my code.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

//*************************************

class Base {
public:

  typedef int (Base::*BaseThunk)();

  virtual int execute(BaseThunk x) {return 0;}

};

//*************************************

class Derived : public Base {
public:

  typedef int (Derived::*DerivedThunk)();

  int execute(BaseThunk step) {
    return (this->*step)(); //Is this OK ? step is really a DerivedThunk.
  }

  int f1() { cout<<"1\n";return 1;}
  int f2() { cout<<"2\n";return 2;}
  int f3() { cout<<"3\n";return 3;}

  static DerivedThunk steps[];
};

//Here is an array of pointers to member functions of the Derived class.
Derived::DerivedThunk Derived::steps[] = {&Derived::f1, &Derived::f2, &Derived::f3};

//*************************************

class Intermediate : public Base {
public:

  void f(void *x) { //I am worried about using void pointer here !

    BaseThunk *seq = reinterpret_cast<BaseThunk *>(x);

    Derived d;
    d.execute(seq[2]);
  }

};

//*************************************

int main() {
  Intermediate b;

  b.f(&Derived::steps);
}
```

Comment: Note that a function pointers, member pointers and member function pointers are not guaranteed to be compatible to `void*`. It's possible they may be larger and casting to `void*` and back is not guaranteed to yield the original value. Casting a function pointer to an object pointer is [conditionally supported](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.reinterpret.cast#6) and not all implementations allow it.

Comment: The function f is receiving a pointer to an array of DerivedThunk::* (which I think is a normal data pointer), into a void*. It then reinterprets the void* as a BaseThunk* to allow indexing it.  I think the array to pointer part is legal, but implicitly BaseThunk and DerivedThunk are assumed to be the same size. Not so sure that would always be true.

Comment: You can use `static_cast` here (which helps avoid the confusion about object pointers *vs.* pointers to members).  That doesn’t answer your question, though, since `void*` is still involved, as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concern about `void*` is well founded: this is **undefined behavior** because (in `Intermediate::f`) you’re performing pointer arithmetic on, and reading through, a pointer that doesn’t match the array’s type.

The good news is that there is an easy fix: since the purpose of your arrays is to have derived-class functions be called given only a `Base&` and a `BaseThunk`, you can **store** that type:

```
Base::BaseThunk Derived::steps[]=
  {static_cast<BaseThunk>(&Derived::f1),
   …};
```

The `static_cast`s are somewhat verbose, but totally legitimate so long as you **use** the resulting `BaseThunk` objects with an object whose type is or is derived from `Derived`.  You don’t even have to get a `Derived*` first:

```
int Base::execute(BaseThunk x)  // no need to be virtual
{return (this->*x)();}
```

Comment: Thank you. I had not thought of using static_cast in the array definition. Davis Herring seems to have been thinking in a similar direction.   Your solution works fine for me, since the arrays will be machine generated anyway (the problem relates to a compiler that generates C++ source),  and I don't really care if it is verbose.  'execute' is declared virtual because it needs to be virtual in my actual problem.  I should have removed it from the toy code that I posted.

Comment: @user1759557: I would say that Davis Herring was thinking in a *very* similar direction, although that was just about the `reinterpret_cast`.  I’m glad this approach works for you, although the cast could always be put in a function with a short name for typing/reading convenience.

Comment: Sorry Davis, I may not have understood your comment completely when I read it.  I thought you were saying that I could replace the reinterpret_cast of the void* in 'Intermediate' with static_cast.  It now seems like you were referring to the array, but I did not get it first time around.  I used a #define to shorten the code, but your idea of using a function is much neater, and of course the compiler will optimise it away.

Comment: @user1759557: No, you were right—I first commented on the cast you did use, and then wrote an answer about the cast that would work.

Comment: Doh !  I hadn't noticed the correct answer was from the same person (you) that also commented.  I was trying to give credit for the comment.